# subprocess run/call not working with passing variables

Tags: python-3.x

Trying to run UNIX commands in my script but not having much luck. What I actually want to do is loop through the list of directories below, zip the files in there with a linux command then move the files somewhere else. Haven't even managed to get it to run a test command yet. See below:

```
    #!/bin/python3

    import subprocess

    Env="test/"
    someHome = "/app/home/" + Env
    logDir = "/current/log/"
    directoryNames=("dir1", "dir2", "dir3", "dir4",
                    "dir5", "dir6", "dir7", "dir8", "dir9",
                    "dir10", "dir11", "dir12")

    for eachDir in directoryNames:
        args = someHome + eachDir + logDir
        subprocess.run(['cd ', args], shell=True)
        subprocess.run('pwd')
```

Comment: Why not use the functions in [`os`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html) instead of subprocesses for basic filesystem operations?

Comment: I thought os was deprecated? If I did use os, would I be able to pass the variables to it?

Comment: I see nothing in the `os` documentation that indicates that it's deprecated. Your second question depends on what function and what variables you're talking about.

Comment: So am currently trying: 

    os.system('"cd" "{}"'.format(args))
    os.system('"pwd"')

It just keeps changing to the home directory whereas I want it to change to the actual args directory for the current loop cycle each time.

Comment: Ignore `os.system()`. Try [`os.chdir()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.chdir) and [`os.getcwd()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.getcwd).